# Python - Multirprocessing, give each processor an email from a text file

Tags: python, text, multiprocess

So I have been playing around with Multiprocessing and I was thinking to upgrade my knowledge where I can read the first sentence from the text file for process 1 then the second sentence for process 2 etc...

```
txt file:

helloworld@world.com
helloworld2@world.com
helloworld3@world.com
helloworld4@world.com
helloworld5@world.com
```

and this is how the code is looking:

```
def info(thread):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    runit()


def runit():

    log("Profile-" + str(prod) + Fore.GREEN + ' - ' + email)
    #From here I can then use the email for each worker basically. Or thats the plan atleast. Theplan is that every worker will have its own email that can be used in here.
    sys.exit()

def main():
    user_input = 0
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(Fore.WHITE + 'How many tasks do you wanna run? [NUMBERS] \n' + Fore.RESET))
        except ValueError:
            print(Fore.RED + "Stop being stupid" + Fore.RESET)
            continue
        else:
            with open('email.txt') as f:
                content = f.readlines()
            content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]

            try:
                for i, email in enumerate(content):
                    print(email)

            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)

            HowManyThread = user_input
            i = 0
            jobs = []
            for i in range(HowManyThread):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=info, args=(str(i),))
                jobs.append(p)
                time.sleep(.5)
                p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                p.join()

            sys.exit()
```

---

Log is just a log message basically, Nothing special

### Fore.COLOR <-- Colorama

However, I have completely no idea what I should do to actually make each process take each email row. So basically....

```
Process-1 to take helloworld@world.com
Process-2 to take helloworld2@world.com
Process-3 to take helloworld3@world.com
Process-4 to take helloworld4@world.com
Process-5 to take helloworld5@world.com
```

What are the suggestions on how I can do this? I'm completely off and have absolutely no idea on how to move forward.

---

Update

```
from multiprocessing import pool, Process, Queue
from tqdm import tqdm

with open('email.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

global email_list
email_list = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]


def info(thread):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    runit()


def runit(email_index):
    email = email_list[email_index]

    log("Profile-" + str(prod) + Fore.GREEN + ' - ' + email)
    sys.exit()



def main():
    wipe()
    text()
    Infotext = "First name : Last name : Email: : Random char + Street"
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(Infotext, f)
        f.write("\n")

    with Pool(8) as pool:
        result_list = list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(, range(len(email_list)), chunksize=5), total=len(email_list))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(traceback.print_exc())
        print(traceback)
```

Comment: You could simply pass one line to each `Process` like `args=(content[i], )`, then run a `Pool` as the doc suggests. Most of the time cross-process memory access is unnecessary.

Comment: What do you mean by running a Pool?

Comment: it is the very first paragraph in https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#introduction

Comment: Hmm. I quite dont understand, I mean compare to mine, whats the big difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach delegates the multiprocessing to a pool of workers, each of which receives a chunk of indices and processes these indices a single line at a time (the choice of `poolsize=8` and `chunksize=5` here is arbitrary and can be tuned according to your requirements).

The result of all workers is then collected into a final list. Note that `imap_unordered` is only appropriate if you don't care about the order in which the lines are processed (i.e. `result_list` does not maintain the original order of `content`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# progress bar to track your multiproc
from tqdm import tqdm

with open('email.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# this list will be accessed by each worker
global email_list
email_list = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]

# define function that worker will apply to each email
# it gets sent an index for the list of emails
# it accesses the email at that index, performs its function and returns
def runit(email_index):
    email = email_list[email_index]
    # do the stuff you're interested in for a single email

# run the multiprocessing to get your results
# this sends the indexes for the emails out to the workers
# and collects the results of runit into result list
with Pool(8) as pool:                                                
  result_list = list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(runit,    
                          range(len(email_list)), chunksize=5),                 
                          total=len(email_list)))
```

Comment: Oh this seems like too new for me everything, Its pretty hard to understand this for me since its completely new for me... However I mean okey if we go from your code and as you can see in my code where I have `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(str(i),))` where target=main meaning it will then run inside the main with each worker, correct. How would I do main in this case?

Comment: There I assume you'd be delegating the `main` function to be run by each worker (which you haven't provided in your code).

The above just assumes a list of lines derived from your content, and a function `worker_function` that you define that operates on a single row of content and does whatever you need it to (you could adapt the body of your `main` function to go here). What are your original jobs doing?

Comment: I have upgraded my script now that might be easier to see now. I added comment. Basically if you check the code in method runit() - that's where I want that each  worker will have his own email where I can use it there... @twolffpiggott

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update. So what I've called `worker_function` is basically your `runit` function. It will receive a single email at a time from the global `line_list` (list of emails). Then `result_list` contains the processed result of each email, from all workers.

Comment: Do you mind if you could update your code so I know what I am looking for, Because im so confused I would say right now haha!

Comment: Looking now! But what about the Pool, Will that also run the runit method for each worker? Basically each worker will do the whole runit() method

Comment: I've updated to clarify. Yes, each worker performs the `runit` method on a single email at a time. If there are many more emails than workers, the workers will work in parallel, processing one email at a time, with all the results returned in `result_list`.

Comment: I'm trying to run the program with from pathos.multiprocessing import pool but it says cannot import name pool even though I did pip install pool it.

Comment: Whoops- should be upper case Pool. Edited.

Comment: Now its saying `imap_unordered() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'` haha :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172063/discussion-between-twolffpiggott-and-cdnthe2nd).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a pool of worker processes - even if for you use case, I really wonder whether threads (or multiprocessing.dummy) would not be enough.

A pool starts the asked number of worker processes, and you can submit asynchronous tasks to the pool that will be handled by the first free worked.

A stripped down version of your example (no fancy printing, no unnecessary reading of a sequential file in a list) could be:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def runit(prod, email):

    print("Profile-" + str(prod) + ' - ' + email)
    #From here I can then use the email for each worker basically. Or thats the plan atleast. Theplan is that every worker will have its own email that can be used in here.
    # sys.exit() # NEVER CALL EXPLICITELY sys.exit() in a worker process
    time.sleep(1) # to add a delay inside each task

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            HowManyThread = int(input(
                'How many tasks do you wanna run? [NUMBERS] \n'))
        except ValueError:
            print("Stop being stupid")
            continue

        if HowManyThread == 0: break

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(HowManyThread)
        with open('email.txt') as f:
            for i, email in enumerate(f):
                email = email.strip()
                # runit will be runned by a worker process
                pool.apply_async(runit, (i, email))

        pool.close()         # no more task to add
        pool.join()          # wait for last worker to end

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```